# is there a way to put a thread into sleep from outside of the thread?

Tags: python

```
import time
import threading


def do_something():
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print('I am alive')


def main():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print('Hello')


daemon_thread = threading.Thread(target=do_something, daemon=True)
daemon_thread.start()
main()
```

Is there a way I be able to put `daemon_thread` to sleep for example for 3 seconds from outside of `do_something()`? I mean something hypothetical like `daemon_thread.sleep(3)`?

Comment: You could use a [`queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) to communicate the sleep command to the thread.

Comment: @LutzHorn Did you create a new account?

Comment: @MarounMaroun ?

Comment: @LutzHorn Maybe it's early morning effect, but I remember you once had a different SO account.

Comment: I see. Yes, I had other accounts before. But the very low quality of questions and the wast of time SO is made me delete them ;) Let's see how long I can stand the ignorance of people trying to program this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a counter for half seconds and then make the sleep function increment that counter:

```
lock = Lock()
counter = 0


def do_something():
    global counter
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        with lock:
            if counter == 0:
                print('I am alive')
            else:
                counter -= 1


def increment(seconds):
    global counter
    with lock:
        counter += 2*seconds


# after starting thread

increment(3)  # make the thread wait three seconds before continuing
```